# Как писать чат бота для соц.сети?

Tags: c#, api, бот, chat

Здравствуйте! 
Может кто подскажет какую-нибудь классную статью по теме? Все что видел - для простеньких-препростеньких ботов. Множество статей, которые учат пользоваться апи. 
Пытаюсь написать уже в 3 раз. И каждый раз вроде бы продуманная архитектура кода начинает требовать костыли. 1,2,3 костыля и от изначальной архитектуры - шиш. Баг на баге, багом подгоняет. Ну, думаю, понятно изложил)
Мне бы что-нибудь почитать. Что-нибудь, где будет рассказываться о том, как такой код должен выглядеть. Паттерн что ле.

Comment: О чем вопрос, о шаблонах проектирования или о написании ботов для соцсетей? Поясните суть вопроса.

Comment: О шаблоне для бота со сети, не?)

Comment: Посмотри [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для телеграмма и вк ботов писать не сложно и интересно, вот ссылка на документацию https://vk.com/dev/api_requests

Если собираетесь писать чат бота для вк то знайте обычное сообщение предет не в той кодировке которая понятна человеку.

```
//using System.Net;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string url = (method); // вместо method пишете тот запрос который вам нужно выполнить.
var json = cl.DownloadString(url); // var json будет представлять из себя переменую типа String в которой будет находиться ответ сервера.
```

Comment: Да с апи то я знаком. И вообщем-то не плохо.

Comment: Да с апи то я знаком. И вообщем-то не плохо.
Проблема у меня в том, что я не могу придумать достаточно универсальный алгоритм. 
Везде пример для работы с базой типа (вопрос:ответ). Мне это не подходит. Мне нужно ботом задавать вопросы и собирать от пользователя некую информацию. При этом эта информация может быть неверной, тогда нужно уточнять и т.д.
т.е. алгоритм будет изменяться в зависимости от ответов пользователя. 
Ближайший пример: текстовые квесты.

Comment: т.е. более красивое решение, кроме огромного древа условий на ум не приходит?
(Я уже описываю логику в блокноте. Описал лишь треть и уже 80 строк=(()

Comment: Ну мой должен заказывать такси. Only for friends. Так что на схожесть с другими не смотрю)

Comment: На сколько я знаю GoogleMapApi - платное... Так что для начала, нужно хоть какого-то бота накалякать)

Answer (score 0):

Про паттерн правильно написали. Потому что никаких мифических ботов и искусственного интеллекта не существует - есть паттерны программирования и алгоритмы.

Почитайте `Эрик Фримен "Паттерны проектирования"`. Автор **КРАЙНЕ** доступно объясняет смысл и учит применять основные паттерны. Примеры на C#.

*Ну это на случай если, все-таки, хотите научиться программировать. А если тупо нужен бот, то гуглите лучше.*